# Brazil Sitecore User Group: August 15th, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Date/Time (EST): Tuesday, August 15, 2017, 6:00 PM EST

Date/Time (EST): Tuesday, August 15, 2017, 21:00 PM UTC

Location: Vilaj Coworking - Lauro Linhares street , 1281, room 4, Florianópolis

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/SUG-BR/events/241985422/

Twitter: #SUGBR

It will be broadcasted live. More details shortly

AGENDA

18:30 - 19:00 (21:30 - 22:00 UTC) - Networking and snacks (local only - sorry :P)

19:00 - 19:45 (22:00 - 22:45 UTC) - Brainjocks SCORE Reusable Components with Ivan Omorac

19:45 - 20:00 (22:45 - 23:00 UTC) - Q&A

20:10 - 20:55 (23:10 - 23:55 UTC) - Sitecore Publishing Service Module with Sitecore MVP Diego Moretto

20:55 - 21:10 (23:55 - 00:10 UTC) - Q&A

Important: All sessions will be presented in English

SESSION 1

Brainjocks SCORE Reusable Components.

Ivan Omorac will be giving an overview of SCORE Snippet and Tile components and discussing how Atomic Design can speed up the development and content assembly process.

SESSION 2

Sitecore Publishing Service Module.
In this session,  Diego Moretto will be diving into the new Sitecore Publishing Service module and some of it's main benefits.

Comment: Do you have a better title?  "Next SUG-BR meeting" makes for a horrible headline :P

Comment: "Community Bulletin promotion begins in 8 days". But please do come up with a better title before it starts showing on site.

Comment: how's that now @MarkCassidy?

Comment: Much better :-)  Since there are no other upcoming listings, pushed the promotion period to 20 days. It is showing on site now :-)

Comment: cool thanks @MarkCassidy! Appreciate it :-)